# Interstitial Ads coming full screen on screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, interstitial

Hi I am using Admob Interstitial ads in my android application but Interstitial Ads are coming full screen in the application but I want to display Interstitial ads Like a banner ads.

Here my ads code:

```
 private InterstitialAd interstitialAds = null;
this.interstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this, "ca-app-pub-25842888517785");
        this.interstitialAds.setAdListener(this);
        AdRequest adr = new AdRequest();
        // add your test device here
        adr.addTestDevice("8E452640BC83C672B070CDCA8AB9B06B");
        interstitialAds.loadAd(adr);
```

Is there any way to create interstitial ads in my Layout xml file like a ads view?

Please Suggest Me
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of a interstital ad is to take full screen :

"Banners are small ads that when touched typically take the user to some form of full-screen in-app browsing experience.

Interstitials, on the other hand, immediately present rich HTML5 experiences or "web apps" at natural app transition points such as launch, video pre-roll or game level load. Web apps are in-app browsing experiences with a simple close button rather than any navigation bar—the content provides its own internal navigation scheme. Interstitial ads are typically more expensive and subject to impression constraints."

You can see the rest here : [InterstitalAds](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced)

You need to search for another ad provider that can do it.